# Did John Glenn really ask for that?

Tags: historical-accuracy, hidden-figures

In *Hidden Figures* when John Glenn's rocket was about to be launched into space there was some uncertainty regarding the calculation results provided by IBM 7090. Al Harrison was [discussing](http://s3.foxmovies.com/foxmovies/production/films/123/assets/hidden_figures_screenplay.pdf-5183735384.pdf) this with the astronaut:

> AL HARRISON (ON PHONE)
>
> The IBM has been spot on up to this point, John, but we’ll run it
>   again, see what it comes up with.
>
> JOHN GLENN ON THE PHONE AT THE CAPE
>
> To be honest with you, Al...when I fly, I fly the machine and now I
>   feel like the machines are flying me.
>
> AL HARRISON
>
> We’re on the same page. We’re staying on the ground until this works
>   out our way. Stay tuned.
>
> JOHN GLENN
>
> **Let’s get the girl to check the numbers.**
>
> AL HARRISON
>
> The girl?
>
> JOHN GLENN
>
> **Yes, sir. The smart one. If she says they’re good, I’m ready to go.**

I'm curious if Glenn asking specifically for Katherine G. Johnson is a historical fact. The movie is based on a non-fiction [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Figures_(book)) of the same name, I'm wondering if this event is described there or in any other source.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2651/49).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [IMDB.com trivia section](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4846340/trivia?item=tr3272892):

> While John Glenn did specifically request that Katherine Johnson review all of the numbers for the Friendship 7 mission before he would agree to go through with it, he did so weeks before the mission actually took place, not when the countdown to launch was nearing at Cape Canaveral.

From the woman herself:

Comment: Amazing to think that he actually asked for her specifically.

Comment: What was dramatized in the movie was Glenn making the call in his spacesuit just prior to launch. In reality he made the request several weeks before the launch and it took Katherine Johnson a few days to do the calculation.